# Google API Vision - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, api, vision

I'm trying to run the [Google Api Vision sample code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries) but I'm getting this error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;**

These are the characteristics of my project:

**1-POM.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.multiedro</groupId>
    <artifactId>vision</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>API Vision</name>
    <description>Estudando a api vision</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
            <version>0.18.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**2- Class**

```
package br.com.visio;

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.vision.spi.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QuickstartSample {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create();

        // The path to the image file to annotate
        String fileName = "/home/thiago/Imagens/demo-image.jpg";


        // Reads the image file into memory
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

        // Builds the image annotation request
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();

        AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
        requests.add(request);

        // Performs label detection on the image file
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }

            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
                annotation.getAllFields().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", k, v.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3- Google Cloud SDK**
I used the command: gcloud auth application-default login

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same error, have tried removing dependencies, just will not work :)

Comment: same issue here